# Azure app service container crash with "Could not load file or assembly" on ASP.NET Core MVC .NET 6

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I am trying to deploy my .NET 6 asp.net core web app but I'm getting a weird error when trying to do so:
[image: error]
I don't understand why it is searching for .NET 7 packages when my project and stack is on 6.

I tried ZIP deploy through VS and automated through GitHub to no avail. My app worked fine the other day all I did was switch to a Basic B1 plan from Standard S1 to reduce cost.

Comment: Can you please share you .csproj file?

Comment: @GuruStron here it is: https://github.com/vassdeniss/EasyRank-Web-App/blob/main/EasyRank/EasyRank.Web/EasyRank.Web.csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to your Github Actions. You're building the entire solution, but your project EasyRank.Tests.Common uses a different version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.0, while the others are using 6.0.10. Internally it has a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions and they are conflicting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Trying it out right away!

Comment: YOU are an ABSOULUTE legend! I never thought to check the other projects! Thank you so much!!!